# DNS server returns valid IP, but browser can't find server?

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq

OK so I have my Raspberry Pi running a DNS server (dnsmasq), and I have my router set up to use it as the DNS server for the whole network. This was working perfectly until a few hours ago when I added some stuff to the hosts file (all valid). Now, for example, going to `local.dev` in chrome gives "Oops! Google Chrome could not find local.dev"... Even `apple.com` (which isn't even mentioned in the hosts file) is invalid. That's the only non-hosts site I've found that's still invalid

THe really weird thing is, `dig apple.com` from one of my network computers (inside the network, and accessing my raspberry pi DNS server) returns WORKING IP addresses, which work in chrome! Screenshot shows `dig apple.com` results.. Any help would be great, thanks

[image]

EDIT:
Ok so the contents of my `resolv.conf` is just `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, that's it. My router is at 10.0.1.1, and the Raspberry Pi (with dnsmasq) is at 10.0.1.3 (the screenshot shows it's using this as its server).

I have restored the hosts file but the same problem persists. Very strange

Comment: Could you add the contents of /etc/resolv.conf and the ip address of the router and dnsmasq server to the question? They might give a better grasp at the issue.

Comment: Have you try to restore previous contents of hosts file and test whether still works ? And than add new stuff - line by line - and test it.

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem still unsolved? Have you restarted everything after you made the change(s), including the dnsmasq service, the browser, and/or even the entire system?

To me, I have to [restart the dnsmasq service to make it listen to the correct address](http://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/dnsmasq-installation-configuration-5/)